# Plotting certain portion of the image produced from the whole data

Tags: python, image, plot

Simple codes below to plot candlestick chart from stock data, showing 60 days moving average.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\AAPL.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)

data['MA60'] = data['Close'].rolling(window=60).mean()

cl =candlestick2_ohlc(ax=ax1,opens=data['Open'],
highs=data['High'],lows=data['Low'],
closes=data['Close'],width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', 
colordown='#db3f3f')

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(data['Date'], fontsize=6, rotation=-90)
ax2.plot(data.Date, data['MA60'], label='MA_60')

plt.show()   # plt.show() shall be after "plt.savefig" otherwise outputs an empty image file.
```

Above code looks clumsy but works ok.

The data has 90 rows so no problem to show the 60 days moving average.

But I only want a portion of the chart, i.e. the recent 45 days.

If the code only read and use the recent 45 days data, it's unable to produce a chart with 60MA.

So I want to produce using the whole 90 days (so 60MA is there), and only show and save the right half portion of the image.

```
plt.savefig('C:\\AAPL.png')
img = plt.imread('C:\\AAPL.png')
print(img.shape)   # (480, 640, 4)
img_cropped = img[:, 320:, :] # right half of the image
img_cropped.savefig('C:\\AAPL-1.png')
```

It doesn't work out.

What's the proper and decent way, that can have certain portion of the image produced from the whole data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were so close, you only went wrong on the last line! When you loaded the plot back in with `plt.imread()` it became an **image** rather than a figure, so you you must use `plt.imsave()` to save it on your last line:

```
plt.imsave('result.png',img_cropped)
```

Comment: thank you for the advice. It works, but the image is purely the right half of the image, without the y-axis. Is there way a plot half? I mean, like a complete chart, but only showing the wanted portion. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Sorry. I will need to think harder...